# Write Raw Numbers to Disk

Tags: python, c++, disk, diskspace

It occurred to me that I have no idea how to write raw numerical values to disk.
How would I do this in Python or C++?!

I'm running some simulations and writing intermediate results to disk so that it doesn't start from scratch if it crashes.
Sadly these values chomp up gigabytes upon gigabytes of space on my hard drive.

Would writing the numerical values to disk as floats take up significantly less disk space or is there some other overhead I'm not considering?

Comment: How are you writing to disk?

Comment: How many significant digits are written to disk?  How often (e.g. once a second, once a minute, as fast as the loop can go, ...)?

Comment: Generally writing the full number and writing as fast as can be written.
Originally writing using write csv or through regular Python IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most versatile and powerful option is to use the [HDF5 format](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/), with the help of the [Python interface](http://www.h5py.org/). From the website:

> It lets you store huge amounts of numerical data, and easily
>   manipulate that data from NumPy. For example, you can slice into
>   multi-terabyte datasets stored on disk, as if they were real NumPy
>   arrays. Thousands of datasets can be stored in a single file,
>   categorized and tagged however you want

It also has a [C++ API](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/).

The HDF5 format is widely used in the scientific computing community and is read/written by many software. Data in the HDF5 format can be manipulated rapidly with the [parallel utility tools](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/PHDF5/).

Comment: this is the solution that i will use since it is such a complete solution that i skipped over.  thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can roll your own binary format and use that, but it's probably a bad idea.

If you're using Python to deal with numeric data, you're almost certainly using `numpy`. If you're not using `numpy`, you should look in to using `numpy`, it's great.

Once you've got your data in a `numpy` array, you can just use their [`save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) method.

Comment: how have i never seen the simple little "save" function before?!

this looks great!

Answer (score 2):

The general method in Python is to use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

```
import struct
print struct.pack("!d", 3.14159)
```

(You can choose what byte order to use—I use `!` to indicate network byte order for portability—or use no indicator to use the native byte ordering. Actually, I'm not sure if IEEE 754 specifies a byte ordering, so I'm not sure what to recommend. Maybe using the default is best.)

Answer (score 1):

Before you optimize, make sure you are at least doing something like this (storing your numeric type in its binary representation on disk). If you are at this point and the file sizes are still too large, you can consider different types of compressed formats.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

typedef int32_t my_numeric_type;

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    {
        ofstream output_file("numbers.dat", ios::binary);
        if( !output_file )
        {
            cout << "Failed to open file for writing" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        for( my_numeric_type i = 0 ; i <= 1000; ++i )
            output_file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i), sizeof(i));
    }

    {
        ifstream input_file("numbers.dat", ios::binary);
        if( !input_file )
        {
            cout << "Failed to open file for reading" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        my_numeric_type i;
        while( input_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof(i)) )
            cout << i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```